# Count and concatenate MySQL entries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count, group-concat

Essentially, I have a table that is like this:

```
FirstName, LastName, Type
Mark, Jones, A
Jim, Smith, B
Joseph, Miller, A
Jim, Smith, A
Jim, Smith, C
Mark, Jones, C
```

What I need to do is be able to display these out in PHP/HTML, like:

`Name | Total Count Per Name | All Type(s) Per Name`

which would look like...

- Mark Jones | 2 | A, C
- Jim Smith | 3 | B, A, C
- Joseph Miller | 1 | A
- Jim Smith | 3 | B, A, C
- Jim Smith | 3 | B, A, C
- Mark Jones | 2 | A, C

I have spent time trying to create a new table based off the initial one, adding these fields, as well as looking at `group_concat`, `array_count_values`, `COUNT`, and `DISTINCT`, along with other loop/array options, and cannot figure this out.

I've found a number of answers that count and concatenate, but the problem here is I need to display each row with the total count/concatenation on each, instead of shortening it.

Comment: Please post some code with an example of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about doing it like this?

```
SELECT aggregated.* FROM table_name t
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName) AS Name,
        COUNT(Type) AS `Total Count Per Name`,
        GROUP_CONCAT(Type SEPARATOR ',') AS `All Type(s) Per Name`
    FROM table_name
    GROUP BY Name) AS aggregated
ON CONCAT(t.FirstName, ' ', t.LastName) = aggregated.Name
```

Comment: This works great. With some slight modification I got it to work: `$query = "
SELECT aggregated.* FROM 'TABLE 1'
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        CONCAT('COL 5', ' ', 'COL 6') AS Name,
        COUNT('COL 20') AS 'Total Count Per Name',
        GROUP_CONCAT('COL 20' SEPARATOR ', ') AS 'All Type(s) Per Name',
        'COL 17' AS Image,
        CONCAT('COL 7', ', ', 'COL 8') AS Location,
        'COL 29' AS Profits
    FROM 'TABLE 1'
    GROUP BY Name) AS aggregated
ON CONCAT('TABLE 1'.'COL 5', ' ', 'TABLE 1'.'COL 6') = aggregated.Name";`

Comment: As you can see I added some fields in the SELECT. I'm wondering if there is a way I can modify that to still show the unique entries for Profit and Image.

Comment: Sure, but you'd have to select them from `TABLE 1` and not from `aggregated`. So the query becomes `SELECT aggregated.*, 'TABLE 1'.'COL 17' AS Image, ...` and so on.

Comment: Hmm, I still can't figure out where exactly this code is supposed to go, is it all supposed to go after `ON CONCAT(t.FirstName, ' ', t.LastName) = aggregated.Name`?

Comment: At the beginning of the main query. Remove them from the `aggregated` view. The `aggregated` view should only have the columns that were already there in my example.

Comment: I got it, I did `SELECT 'TABLE 1'.'COL 17' AS Image, aggregated.* ...` and it worked. Thanks for all your help in pointing me in the right direction and understanding!

Answer (score 1):

Without an ORDER BY clause, the order the rows will be returned in is indeterminate. Nothing wrong with that, by my personal preference is to have the result to be repeatable.

We can use an "inline view" (MySQL calls it a derived table) to get the count and the concatenation of the Type values for (FirstName,LastName).

And then perform a join operation to match the rows from the inline view to each row in the detail table.

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(d.FirstName,' ',d.LastName) AS name
     , c.total_coount_per_name
     , c.all_types_per_name
  FROM mytable d
  JOIN ( SELECT b.FirstName
              , b.LastName
              , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT b.Type ORDER BY b.Type) AS all_types_per_name
              , COUNT(*) AS total_count_per_name
           FROM mytable b
          GROUP 
             BY b.FirstName
              , b.LastName
       ) c
    ON c.FirstName = d.FirstName
   AND c.Last_name = d.LastName
 ORDER BY d.FirstName, d.LastName
```

If you have an `id` column or some other "sequence" column, you can use that to specify the order the rows are to be returned; same thing in the GROUP_CONCAT function. You can omit the DISTINCT keyword from the GROUP_CONCAT if you want repeated values...  `'B,A,B,B,C'`,